# прибавить число к инпуту js

Tags: javascript, jquery

`var nnews = $('#nnews').val();`

как в цикле прибавить +1 число к этому input'у?

Answer (score 3):

```
var nnews = parseInt($('#nnews').val());
while(nnews < 1000){
  nnews++;
  $('#nnews').val(nnews);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

в дополнение к посл. ответу скажу, что если в input будут только числа, то можно ипользовать ф-ю Number(); Она чуть быстрее работает чем parseInt();

Comment: Поддерживаю )))